# Inputing blank space in 2d array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

In cpp how to converted the inputed blank spaces as zero?
for eg my `ar[2][2]`

```
1 
2 3
```

now `ar[0][1]` should be assumed as zero..
what code must be written in c++?

Comment: Read line by line (`std::getline`), then read number by number, and use 0 when line is finished?

Comment: try to solve the simpler problem first. Fill a one dimensional array with user input, eg a `int x[42]` with user input `1 2 3`.

Comment: You may want an istringstream after you get the line into a std::string

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ read file space separated".  There is already a plethora of these questions and answers.  Always search first before posting questions.

Comment: In the first line, how do you know if the `1` is the first value or the second?